# Google Academy Android Google Maps Autocomplete example

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, autocomplete, filter

Well as the title says, i am trying to add an autocomplete field in my app which shows possible addresses, as the user keeps typing(like search on google maps). Well i'm new to this.. I ve found on this page 
https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/autocomplete-android an example of how to do this. The problem is that after trying to implement it in Eclipse, i get errors, which are associated with Filter. I get errors both in the the imports area and the code. Has anyone had a workaround with this example, and has managed make it work???

Specifically:

```
import android.widget.Filter.FilterResults; 

@Override

public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

@Override
             protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }


  protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This code is what gives me the errors. They all have to do with Filter and FilterResults

The import gives me an error "The type android.widget.Filter.FilterResults is not visible" but later in the code i get some different errors like in (1)Filter "The return type is incompatible with ArrayAdapter.getFilter()". 
Any ideas???

Comment: Posting your errors or code would help us answer your question. Did you [follow the steps to set up your Android development environment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)?

Comment: yep,i think so at least. I have other examples running with no problem in my set up.i ve tried changing build path and api level but made no progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are still stuck, the thing is to get ride of this import:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater.Filter;
```

You have to use this one instead:

```
import android.widget.Filter;
```